# Why wont my jsp page show all the objects from my angularjs list in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

JSP

```
<table class="countrys" data-name="tableProductsBuy">
        <tr bgcolor="lightgrey">
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>In Store</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="p in finalList"
        data-ng-click="selectObject(p, $index);"
            data-ng-class="getSelectedObject(p);">
            <td>{{p.product.productId}}</td>
            <td>{{p.product.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{p.unitsOutStore}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <button data-ng-click="buyIt()">Add to Shopping Cart</button>
```

controller

```
$scope.getSelectedObject = function(object) {

    if ($scope.selectedObject.product.productId != undefined) {
        if ($scope.selectedObject.product.productId == object.product.productId) {
            return "selected";
        }
    }
    return "";
};


$scope.selectObject = function(object, index){
    $scope.selectedObject = object; 
}

$scope.finalList = [];
$scope.theListB = [];
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.priceOfProducts = 0;
$scope.buyIt = function(){
    if ($scope.selectedProduct.unitsInStore>0){
        $scope.selectedProduct.unitsInStore--;
        $scope.theListB.push($scope.selectedProduct);
        $scope.priceOfProducts += $scope.selectedProduct.pricePerUnit;
    }else{
        alert("The product ID:" + $scope.selectedProduct.productId +"\n" +
                "With the name:"  + $scope.selectedProduct.productName + "\n"
                +"Is out of stock!");
    }

    $scope.showList();
}

$scope.showList=function(){
    $scope.finalList = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.theListB, function(productFromListB, key){
        var go = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.allSProducts, function(productFromStores, key){
            if(productFromListB.productId == productFromStores.productId){
            //  if(go){
                $scope.object.product = productFromListB;
                $scope.object.unitsOutStore = productFromStores.unitsInStore - productFromListB.unitsInStore;
                $scope.object.maxNumber = productFromStores.unitsInStore;
                $scope.finalList.push($scope.object);
                go = false;
            //  }
            }
        });  
    });
}
```

so in the end, i got the function $scope.showList()
there i have theListB filed with my 10 or more objects
that data i modify and add to finalList with this line:

```
  $scope.finalList.push($scope.object);
```

but on the jsp page, it only shows the last added object in the table row
in ng-repeat...

any sugestions?

Here a pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljfaK.png)

Comment: your `ng-repeat`  loops trough `finalList` not `theListB`

Comment: yes, but in the forEach loop, i make a finalList when i add the objects from theListB with some modifications to the finalList, yes? in showList()

Comment: and your finalList contains more item then displayed with the ng-repeat?

Comment: yes....it contains all of the items from listB and more

Comment: i added a picture, see for urself